# arecord is crashing after 1 min while scheduled with cron on raspi

Tags: cron, audio, raspberry-pi

i'm trying to record a several hours of audio each day at 8:00.
for the cron+arecord test i used intervalls of 10 minutes and tried to record for a duration of
8 min (480 sec):

```
*/10 * * * * arecord -f dat -r 48000 -D hw:2,0 -d 480 -c 2 record`date "+\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M "`.mp3
```

the syntax is vaild as it's producing the files but it stops after 1 min exactly every time it starts.

*the same proccess on my linux mint 19.3 machine is producing usfull files, at the proper length.

please advise :)

**edit**:

even if i try to record with out the cron, the process is killed after several minutes. the longest recording i've managed to get is 2:47

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -f dat -r 48 -D hw:2,0 -d 1800 -v -c 1 /home/pi/record.wav
Recording WAVE '/home/pi/record.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
Hardware PCM card 2 'USB PnP Sound Device' device 0 subdevice 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 1
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 24000
  period_size  : 6000
  period_time  : 125000
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 6000
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 24000
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1572864000
  appl_ptr     : 0
  hw_ptr       : 0
Killed
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what caused it, but i flashed the OS and started over and it took care of the problem. maybe someone messesd up with the sound & audio def of that specific raspberry (it's a group project so i can't really tell who did it and when).
so...